# Кто знает, что за view на картинке и где его найти?

Tags: java, android

Меня интересуют этот своеобразный виджет, очень похожий на tablayout, но располагается снизу. Где его можно найти? (используется в instagram)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самому сверстать

Answer (score 0):

Может быть "BottomNavigationView" если интересно, посмотрите здесь [Bottom Navigation](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/)